# Excel VBA Replace Character

Tags: vba, replace, special-characters

I tried looking around for this particular problem, but couldn't find it.

I am trying to replace an assortment of characters in a string.

I tried looping through the characters using their character codes, but my code will ?randomly? delete the entire string instead of just the special characters. (basically I just want the letters and numbers from the string) EG. ABC-3.3%H14T-6 I would just want ABC33H14T6

What is strange about this (to me) is that my code will delete the string on a random character, it's not always chr(41) or whatever, it changes each time I run the code.. is it maybe a formatting issue?

```
For Char = 33 To 47
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(FRow, 44).Replace What:=Chr(Char), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
Next Char
```

I would give you the bulk of my code, but it is work-sensitive.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks guys.

Comment: Nevermind I just realized Chr(42) was the culprit. I dunno what I was smoking to think it was random.
Chr(42) = *

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm dumb Chr(42) = *

which would replace everything. durr